# How can i use redisService inside a spock test i need to cleanup the redis database for setup and cleanup

Tags: java, grails, redis

I have a class that stores a value in redis. 
When i test it, it works properly. If i run it for the second tome it will fail as there is an entry on redis already. I want to cleanup the redis database before running the test and after it is finished but i haven't been able to do that.

I am running grails 2.2.4.

I have tried the `@autowired` annotation,`@mock(RedisService)`, also  `redisService = grails.util.Holders.applicationContext.getBean('redisService') as RedisService`  and i am not able to create an instance of the redisService.

This is what i am trying to do:

```
redisService.withRedis { Jedis redis ->
                redis.del("test")
            }
```

The expected result would be that the entry is deleted from redis.

I have gotten several errors like:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'resource' on null object
and
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are like me wondering how exactly am I going to do that:

```
@Mock(RedisService) // above class definition

def setup(){
    def redisPoolMock = new Object()
    redisPoolMock.metaClass.getResource =  { ->
        throw new JedisConnectionException('Generated by a mocked redisPool')
        // Or you can put the value in here maybe
    }
    redisService = new RedisService()
    redisService.redisPool = redisPoolMock
    service.redisService = redisService
}
```

And now you can test your service.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i just have to use the annotation @Mock(RedisService) and metaClass when calling redis.